# Insert into Elasticsearch from json file

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a json file which has multiple instances of this sample:

```
{
    "index": {
        "_type": "Tally_Reports",
        "_index": "product"
    },
    "properties": {
        "Net_Amount": {
            "type": "float"
        },
        "Travel_Date": {
            "type": "date"
        },
        "SalesID": {
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}

{
    "Net_Amount": "670.0",
    "Travel_Date": "14/12/2014",
    "SalesID": "somestring"
}
```

After pushing this data when I check the mapping for the index `product` , I realise that the type of `Travel_Date` and `Net_Amount` are still, both `string` and `not_analyzed`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't put Net_Amount in double quotes.

Comment: @user2486495: you mean the name "Net_Amount" or the value `670`?

Comment: I mean value of Net_Amount